# Linux - SO file not found

Tags: c++, c, linux, environment-variables, shared-libraries

I have a program which requires `liblog4cpp` installed to run.

Now, I want the program to run on another machine without `liblog4cpp`. So I just find the `log4cpp.so` and move it to the same directory of my program. But at running error reported:

> error while loading shared libraries: liblog4cpp.so.4: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

Am I doing it right? How can I tell the program to find the SO file just beside it?

Comment: is the `log4cpp.so` just a symbolic link to `liblog4cpp.so.4`? check with `file log4cpp.so` command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable...  One of the directories on the path should point to the location of your `log4cpp.so` file; also the linux command `ldd` is handy for determining which shared object libraries are being used in your executable.  The syntax is `ldd <executable>`.

Comment: 'ldd log4cpp.so' is more specific

Answer (score 10):

In addition to what others are suggesting, consider adding the file to the dynamic linker's cache. You can do it like this:

```
ldconfig -l /path/to/lib/liblog4.so.4
```

To add it to the loader's cache use the following command: `ldconfig`

Then in order to verify that it was correctly added, run this:

```
ldconfig -v | grep liblog
```

Answer (score 7):

assuming that the path where the `.so` file/s is available is `/path` you can also avoid to export an environment variable and just use

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path ./myProgram
```

beware the fact that if you do:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path
```

you are resetting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to a single value `/path` and losing anything you added before to this environment variable. If you want to add a value without losing the previous ones

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path
```

Answer (score 6):

In the rc script from where you are launching your program, you should set the LD_LIBRARAY_PATH before launching the application. Remember, the .so are the shared libraries, it is required at the run time to link. Thus, it should be available in the standard path like /usr/lib before launching.
In case it is not copied in the standard path like /usr/lib then specify the path by  using the following.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<new_path_of_so>:$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
```

Ideally, I would have placed this .so in the standard path like /usr/lib. If it is installed in the standard path, then there is no need to set the above path. Remember, to make your program better, put the new path in ldconfig.conf.

You can debug such errors by using the following.

```
$strace <binary_name>
```

to know the so dependencies

```
$ldd <binary_name>
```

For further, check the below link.

http://www.tune2wizard.com/sharedobject-crash/

Answer (score 4):

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the path of the library.  This env variable works much like the PATH variable.  It can contain multiple paths separated by :.

Answer (score 2):

After adding shared objects (or shared libraries `lib*.so*`, or such symbolic links)  to system directories like `/usr/lib` or `/lib` known to the dynamic linker [ld-linux.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) (or `ld.so`) you need to run [ldconfig(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html)

You could also add them to `/usr/local/lib/` but then be sure that `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or some file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`) .mentions that directory (and run `ldconfig` after changing it)