# Cmake find_package directory path missing

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm pretty new to linux and cmake and I'm studying this book https://github.com/gaoxiang12/slambook2 and running into a library linkage problem when compiling the code snippet under ch3/visualgeometry which use Pagolin.

After find_package(Pagonlin REQUIRED), I try to print the file path in CMakeLists, it's empty, but the lib names are there, which confuses me. See attached code:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )
project( visualizeGeometry )
   
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++17")
   
include_directories( "/usr/include/eigen3" )
   
find_package( Pangolin REQUIRED )
message("Pangolin include dir: ${Pangolin_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("Pangolin libs: ${Pangolin_LIBRARIES}")
include_directories( ${Pangolin_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
  
add_executable( visualizeGeometry visualizeGeometry.cpp )
target_link_libraries( visualizeGeometry ${Pangolin_LIBRARIES} )
```

compile and run

```
linyz0100@linyz0100-QEMU-VM:~/Desktop/slambook2/ch3/visualizeGeometry/build$ cmake ..
Pangolin include dir: 
Pangolin libs: pango_core;pango_display;pango_geometry;pango_glgeometry;pango_image;pango_opengl;pango_packetstream;pango_plot;pango_python;pango_scene;pango_tools;pango_vars;pango_video;pango_windowing;tinyobj
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/linyz0100/Desktop/slambook2/ch3/visualizeGeometry/build
linyz0100@linyz0100-QEMU-VM:~/Desktop/slambook2/ch3/visualizeGeometry/build$ make
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target visualizeGeometry
[100%] Built target visualizeGeometry
linyz0100@linyz0100-QEMU-VM:~/Desktop/slambook2/ch3/visualizeGeometry/build$ ./visualizeGeometry 
./visualizeGeometry: error while loading shared libraries: libpango_windowing.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I suspect that cmake does not find the directory path? It compiles successfully, but the executable can't locate the the library. I think Pagolin is correctly installed, as you can see the .so files under usr/local/lib

shared libs

```
linyz0100@linyz0100-QEMU-VM:/usr/local/lib$ ls
cmake                   libpango_opengl.so        libpango_vars.so
libpango_core.so        libpango_packetstream.so  libpango_video.so
libpango_display.so     libpango_plot.so          libpango_windowing.so
libpango_geometry.so    libpango_python.so        libtinyobj.so
libpango_glgeometry.so  libpango_scene.so         python3.10
libpango_image.so       libpango_tools.so
```

Can someone explain this process to me? What is missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `find_package(Pagonlin REQUIRED)` and do exactly what CMake tells you if you get an error.

Comment: Thanks. Just edited. I added REQUIRED but the results are the same. CMake doesn't throw an error, but the executable can't find the library.

Comment: `./visualizeGeometry: error while loading shared libraries: libpango_windowing.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` appears to be an execution problem and not a CMake issue. Is /usr/local/lib in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547551/linux-so-file-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547551/linux-so-file-not-found)

Comment: Thank you. that is indeed the problem. I cd into where I built Pagolin and "sudo ldconfig" and the program runs smoothly. But this way LD_LIBRARY_PATH remains unchanged and does not include /user/local/lib. I wonder which method is better though